# Select rows where max date is less than December 31st of the previous year

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL developer. I am trying to select rows where max date is less than December 31st of the previous year. I tried this query below but kept getting an error.

```
Select ORG_ID, STS_DTE 
from Table1 
Group By RC_ORG_ID
Having MAX(STS_DTE)< '31-Dec-' || extract (year from SYSDATE-1)
```

Comment: *but kept getting an error* - Should we guess the error text? Please, describe the exact problem you have. What is the type of `STS_DTE`?

Comment: Please always keep silence about error you have got. Select ORG_ID, max(STS_DTE) from Table1 Group By ORG_ID Having MAX(STS_DTE)< '31-Dec-' || extract (year from SYSDATE-1)

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors you will be getting, `'31-Dec-' || extract (year from SYSDATE-1)` will give you the *string* `'31-Dec-2021'` if run today; you probably meant `'31-Dec-' || (extract (year from SYSDATE)-1)` to get `31-Dec-2020`. But that is still a string, so you're relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings. You probably meant `< trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')` if you want to include 31-Dec, or `< trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') - 1` if you really don't want data from that last day.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `trunc()`:

```
having MAX(STS_DTE) < trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') - interval '1 day'
```

I'm not sure if you want `sysdate - interval '1' day`.